# Sampling conditional random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, simulation

I am going to generate a sample of random variables conditioning on a linear constraint. To make it clear, suppose that I want to generate multivariate gaussian $(0,\Sigma)$ conditioning on the plane P:$aX_1+bX_2+cX_3+dX_4=e$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with 1 on the diagonal.

My guess is that, simply generate a sample X of the multivariate gaussian $(0,\Sigma)$, and then project X on to the plane P.

Here comes the questions: how I can verify the guess is correct or not. Should I really compute the exact distribution of the conditional multivariate gaussian, and compare it with that of my guess? Or is there other methods?

Thank you.

Comment: This does not appear to be correct. For instance, consider a degenerate case where $\Sigma$ is a 2x2 matrix with all entries $1$. Then any sample $(X,Y)$ of this distribution would satisfy $X=Y$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$. Hence if we condition $(X,Y)$ to be in the line $\{y=0\}$, then it would be the zero vector almost surely. However, if we project $(X,Y)$ onto the line $\{y=0\}$ then we just get $(X,0)$ which is not zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But now, how can I generate the desired sample given in my question? Conditional on a linear subspace is easy, but for this case, is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

A Gaussian vector of variance matrix $\Sigma=\Sigma_X$ behaves nicely under a linear (or affine) map, $Y=AX+B$. It stays gaussian with variance: $\Sigma_Y=A \Sigma A^T$. If $A=P$ is an orthogonal projection (so $P^T=P=P^2$) and $\Sigma_X$ the identity times $\sigma^2$, then $$\Sigma_Y=P \Sigma_X P^T=\sigma^2 P^2=\sigma^2 P$$ and your new r.v. will have $\sigma^2$ as eigenvalue of multiplicity ${\dim\ }P$ and zero for the rest. I recommend choosing an orthogonal projection; typically what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is the map of Gaussian onto a plane, but I wonder if this map is equivalent with the condition probability of Gaussian on that plane? I think this may not be true, and would like to see how we can make it.

Comment: Not quite sure if this responds, if so the answer is yes: If you introduce new linear coordinates, say  $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$, $Z=Z_1$ where $Z=e$ ($e$ the constant in your notation) corresponds to your plane, and $Y$ to some complementary subspace $E$ of dimension 3, then the conditional pdf $f_{Y,Z}(y,e)/f_Z(e)$ is again gaussian with a variance matrix which may be calculated from my formula when putting $A$ to be the projection matrix along $E$ onto $P$.  and express in the new coordinates. Does this help?